# asp.net web forms get sharepoint username

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, webforms

so i've built a web application in asp.net and c#. That web application will be shown in a sharepoint webpage through i a iframe or something, thats not up to me. What i need to finish the project is a way of getting the sharepoint logged in username.

someone there told me it was simple and could be done with this code:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName
```

however i get these errors:

"The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

"The name 'SPContext' does not exist in the current context."

do you guys have any idea of how to solve this or know any other way to do this?

Comment: Did you include the reference to Sharepoint in your project references?

Comment: nop, nobody told me i had to. do you know where do i get the dll to add?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not running the aspx on the Sharepoint server which is the only way you'd be able to call SPContext to get the currently logged in Sharepoint user.

If you can run custom code on the parent sharepoint page, you could store the LoginName of the current user in the javascript DOM, then access that in your iframe ASP.NET page, assuming that both pages are on the same domain.  You could get that loginName in javascript like this:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('currentLoginName')
```

Comment: im developing the aspx etc in my pc which will later be hosted in something like www.schoolsystem.epbc.com and then in the sharepoint page there will be a iframe pointing to that url. what solutions do i have? the only reason they want it to be inside the sharepoint is so that users can use that top bar to log out etc. which isnt included in my project and thats why i need to catch the logged in user. (otherwise i would make the account system myself. login etc) but they dont want that

Comment: If the Sharepoint site and your custom aspx page are not on the same domain (schoolsystem.epbc.com for example) you won't be able to access any javascript objects on the parent page.  
  
If possible maybe the best way to go forward is to develop your functionality as a custom aspx page in the LAYOUTS folder on the Sharepoint site.  That way you can call the Sharepoint Object Model directly to get the currently logged in user.

Comment: they told me it was gonna be the way i wrote above and i dont think that anything i tell to them will change their minds. do you know of any other way, code-wise or something. what if i managed to get a microsoft.sharepoint.dll somewhere and added it to the references. would it work?

Comment: If the goal is for users to not have to set up a separate username and password for your functionality, then you could use Windows Authentication (assuming they're accessing it from their internal Windows network).  From what you're saying I don't think you're going to be able to use Sharepoint to get the currently logged in user.  Simply including the Microsoft.Sharepoint.DLL is not going to allow you to pull data from a Sharepoint site located on another server.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the target platform to x64 and target framework to .NET 3.5 (4.5 if using vs2012 and Sharpoint 2013).

Answer (score 0):

In sharepoint 2013 I have used `this.Page.User.Identity.Name` and it's work fine for me. Hope can help you.